# History of the planetary flyby for gravitational assist; first conception, mathematical demonstration, plan, and execution?

Tags: history, interplanetary, gravity-assist, flyby, planning

Planetary flybys for gravitational assists are a stable of deep space missions. When did the following things happen?

1. First *documented realization* that gravitational assists in spaceflight were possible and useful
2. First *formal mathematical demonstration* that gravitational assists were possible and useful
3. First *formal mission plan* using a gravitational assist
4. First *execution* of a gravitational assist by a spacecraft

It is possible and likely that one or more of these is also covered by another answer, in that case feel free to link to it and quote a few key parts if that's more convenient. This way several related good answers to different questions can all be cross-referenced in a single location here.

Comment: This might be a candidate for a community wiki answer

Comment: presuming that it is accurate, I think that wikipedia answers a few of these questions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist#Historical_origins.  The answer to the first two questions appear to be "1919", and the fourth question appears to be Luna 3 in 1959.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky thanks; Wikipedia is incorrect or insufficient relatively often, so I think a proper Stack Exchange answer by someone knowledgable with supporting references is best in this case.